# Is it possible to downgrade SQL Enterprise to Standard on an Azure VM?

Tags: azure

We have a VM set up with SQL Enterprise but are not using the extra features so would like to downgrade to the cheaper standard version.  The only place i have seen this possible says that it can be done using separate software but can be risky.  is there a safe way for this to be done?

Comment: This is really a licensing question. Not a programming question. You can apply whatever license you choose.

Answer (score 0):

It is not risky, from my point of view. If you created the VM with a SQL Server from the Azure Gallery, then, as far as i know, (Azure does not look into your VM), even if you try to uninstall it, you will be billed for the same software.
So, i would offer to create the new VM from a plain Windows Server image, and install the SQL Server you need.